# unattended-upgrades sends attachment instead of text

Tags: upgrade, apt, security, mail, unattended-upgrades

I'm trying to setup automatic security updates on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS with an email response:

```
sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades
sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades
# Answered Yes
```

The upgrades work, but I get the following email:

Subject: `unattended-upgrades result for 'ubuntu'` with an empty body and the attachment of `unattended-upgrades result for 'ubuntu'.dat`

Opening the .dat file in a text editor shows everything, but I'd like to just have this as the body

Here is contents of `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`

```
// Automatically upgrade packages from these (origin:archive) pairs
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
};

// Send email to this address for problems or packages upgrades
// If empty or unset then no email is sent, make sure that you
// have a working mail setup on your system. A package that provides
// 'mailx' must be installed.
Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "cron@mydomainname.com";
```

Everything else is commented out

Comment: I can't find anything in the unattended-upgrades source code that would generate MIME or MIME attachments. What mail client are you using?

Comment: Happened with both Outlook 2010 and Gmail web client.  Here is the raw message: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/5803192/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha, thanks for the raw message, that makes all the difference.

The `heirloom-mailx` mailer is trying to be helpful; it isn't the `unattended-upgrades` script itself that is creating the attachments. If you want to keep `heirloom-mailx`, you can try creating a new configuration file to set the `encoding` variable to different values, and use the `MAILRC` environment variable to select the different configuration. Probably some configuration can be found that will just send along the data without any mangling.

Another option would be to use the `bsd-mailx` version of `mailx(1)` instead, it is less helpful and will just send raw data.

Comment: ahh thank you!  I went for the `bsd-mailx` route and it worked perfectly.  Thanks again (I'd upvote by apparently my stackoverflow rep doesnt carry over and I don't have enough rep here to upvote yet)